# Attach an onchange event listener to a textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to attach an onchange event listener to a textarea that updates it's state with the new value.

Here's the code using inline functions:

```
class Textarea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {value: ''};
  }


  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render(){
    //alert("textarea rendered");
    return (
      <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={()=>{this.handleChange}}></textarea>
    );
  }
}
```

The textarea value doesn't update with the above code but it does if I replace the onChange in the below manner:

```
<textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
```

Instead of updating state, if I change the handleChange function to throwing an alert each time the value changes inside the textbox, it works if I remove the value attribute from the textbox.

Comment: `()=>{this.handleChange}` is creating a new inline function that will return the `this.handleChange` method when it is called. You might see it easier if you write `function() { return this.handleChange }.bind(this)` as an experiment. You want to give a function to `onChange` that should be invoked when the event occurs, so `onChange={this.handleChange}` is more accurate.

Comment: You would need to do `onChange={()=>{ this.handleChange(); }}` to actually call your method when the arrow function is called.

Comment: Also you don't have to bind inline functions.

Comment: @Bergi, he needs `e.target.value` to be passed. so it should be `onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value)}`

Answer (score 1):

`React.Component` doesn't bind every function to `this`. It only binds `this` with the `life cycle methods` of the react.

`Arrow functions:`
When you use `arrow functions` the function will automatically get bound to `this`. It's arrow functions feature.

But in your first attempt, you tried the arrow function `() => { this.handleChange }` which is similar to

```
function () {
   this.handleChange; // this is not being called at all.
}
```

The above syntax literally does nothing. try this instead `(evt) => { this.handleChange(evt); }` which is similar to

```
function (evt) {
   this.handleChange(evt); // The event will get passed to the function here.
}
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the `bind` that he already used. In fact it's much better than defining an arrow function in the constructor, as you can properly inherit with prototype methods.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the comment. I didn't look at the binding in the `constructor`.